# Where to store constant data structures in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, constants

I have an angular app with a lot of data that's not dynamic. So a lot of object literals, records, arrays filled with values that are just constant. Is there any benefit of storing these kind of objects in services compared to just importing them individually from a file? I don't plan to write any unit tests.

Comment: Its better to have a folder called constants.
Have typescripts files in that which export const.

Since its just static data, I don't think you require it in services.

Comment: you can store these data structures into separate files inside a folder, grouping them logically

Comment: What if I have a little bit of dynamic things in there, like sending in a variable and setting one property on the otherwise hardcoded object through that variable? Does that change things?

Comment: Can you share more details about some dynamic things. It will be good to share what you have so far, this will help you and others who might be looking for same solution.

Comment: So for an object that might be 99 percent hardcoded but might have one part of a property dynamically set it could be like this: export const getObject = (countryCode: string) => ({ <here's a huge literal object defined with only one of its properties that takes in countrycode in part of its string value> }); Does that belong in a constant file or better in a service? If it should go in a service, why?

Answer (score 1):

I usually store constants in the same directory as components or service

```sh
+ parent
  # I put constants or types shared by both children here
  - parent.constants.ts # Store both constant and interfaces
  + child1
    - child1.component.ts
    - child1.component.scss
    - child1.component.html
    - child1.component.spec.ts
    - child1.constants.ts
  + child2
    - child2.component.ts
    - child2.component.scss
    - child2.component.html
    - child2.component.spec.ts
    - child2.constants.ts

# For constants used throughout the app
# I put them like this

+ app/
+ assets/
+ constants
  - sharks.constant.ts
  - dolphins.constant.ts
+ utils
  - sharks.utils.ts
  - dolphins.utils.ts
```

It's highly based on each one's opinion. Even I might change this after two months or so.

Comment: What if you have an object that just need one part of a string value replaced somewhere. It is 99 percent hardcoded values with a very small dynamic part. Where would you store that object or perhaps function returning that object?

Comment: Updated the answer to your question